# Mail redirect to another server using GApps

Tags: redirect, dns, google-apps

I want to make a mail redirect from `www.domain1.com` to `www.domain2.com`. The problem is that `domain2.com` mail is hosted by Google Apps. All my employees have two mails, `employeeX@domain1.com` hosted in my office and `employeeX@domain2.com` hosted by GApps. I will turn off office servers when I'm sure that all the mail is redirected, so they only need to use one mail.

I don't know if changing `domain1.com` MX register to `mail.domain2.com` will work.

Any suggestion or ideas to make this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you planning to shut down `domain1.com`? If so, I would suggest [adding it as a domain alias](https://support.google.com/a/answer/53295) on your Google Apps account. This will walk you through domain ownership verification as well as updating your MX records.

Once completed, all users in Apps will automatically have an alias @domain1.com. Because of this and the change to MX records, they will continue to receive emails sent to their username@domain1.com right in their inbox for @domain2.com.